# How to sort a file by grade?

Tags: java, arrays, file, sorting

This is a complete program that sorts the file by ID. However, I would like to sort it by grade. I modified it several times but it doesn't seem to work. Could someone please direct me where to change the ID to grade. Also, do you think this code can be simplified or are there any other code simpler than this code.

Sorry for the bad indentation, this source code can also be found [here](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/io/sortFileData.html).

student.txt file:

```
4 A 87 A
5 B 99 A+
1 C 75 A
2 D 55 C
3 E 68 B
```

source:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

    class ShowData implements Comparable {
    int id;
    String name;
    int marks;
    String grade;

    public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
            return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
            return name;
    }

    public void setMarks(int marks) {
            this.marks = marks;
    }

    public int getMarks() {
            return marks;
    }

    public void setGrade(String grade) {
            this.grade = grade;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
            return grade;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object Student) throws ClassCastException {
            if (!(Student instanceof ShowData))
                    throw new ClassCastException("Error");
            int ide = ((ShowData) Student).getId();
            return this.id - ide;
    }
    }



public class SortFile {
    SortFile() {
    int j = 0;
    ShowData data[] = new ShowData[5];
    try {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:/student.txt");
    // Use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text.
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    String strLine;
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    list.add(strLine);
    }

Iterator itr;
    for (itr = list.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
    String str = itr.next().toString();
    String[] splitSt = str.split(" ");
    String id = "", name = "", marks = "", grade = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < splitSt.length; i++) {
    id = splitSt[0];
    name = splitSt[1];
    marks = splitSt[2];
    grade = splitSt[3];
    }
    data[j] = new ShowData();
    data[j].setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
    data[j].setName(name);
    data[j].setMarks(Integer.parseInt(marks));
    data[j].setGrade(grade);
    j++;
    }

Arrays.sort(data);
    File file = new File("C:/new.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    System.out.println("********Sorted by id********");
    String strVal = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ShowData show = data[i];
    int no = show.getId();
    String name = show.getName();
    int marks = show.getMarks();
    String grade = show.getGrade();
    System.out.println(no + " " + name + " " + marks + " " + grade);
    String d = no + " " + name + " " + marks + " " + grade;
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    al.add(d + "\n");
    Iterator itr1 = al.iterator();
    while (itr1.hasNext()) {
    out.write(itr1.next().toString());
    out.newLine();
    }
    }
    out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
            SortFile data = new SortFile();
    }
    }
```

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I think that there's a *serious* issue with copying code from a website verbatim, then asking if there's any problems with the approach.  Take two steps back and start from scratch so that you can reproduce this sort of behavior on demand:  What do you need to read a file in, what portion of the line do you need to key off of to sort the strings, and what methods would that entail?  I see the solution being a fair bit easier than what's being presented here.

Comment: As i mentioned above, i changed the Id to grade to sort it by GRADE. I tried modifying the code several times but did not achieve anything. I didn't want to post the codes that i modified because they contain many errors.

Answer (score 0):

The compareTo() method is currently comparing the IDs, not the grades. Try compare the
marks instead.

Comment: Exactly, so how would i change that to GRADE instead of ID. For instance, when i change return this.id - ide;

to return this.grade- ide;

it gives me an error "bad operand".

Comment: This is because you cannot use (+,-,*,/) on two strings. It looks like the marks are integer representation of the grades, so maybe use this.marks - ((ShowData) Student).getMarks() ?